# homogeneity criteria from the histogram of gray-levels

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to find an image is homogeneous in matlab. my image contains some coins.One way is to use the function improfile to create the intensity profile. I plotted the histogram and i don't know how to measure the homogeneity

```
close all;clear all;
I = imread('coins.png');
bw =( im2bw(I, graythresh(I)));
[L N]= bwlabel(bw);
ele=find(L==3);
Im1=zeros([size(I,1) size(I,2)]);
Im1(ele)=1;
figure,imshow(Im1)
ML=I; ML(Im1==0)= 0; figure, imshow(ML);
figure,imhist(ML(Im1==1))
```

[image]

what we can infer from the histogram? Is it homogeneous?

Comment: Homogeneity can have multiple meanings depending on context. Can you describe in more detail by what you mean? My first impression is that you might be interested in the skewness & kurtosis of the histogram?

Comment: how to calculate skewness and kurtosis of the histogram. I'm interested in intensity homogeneity,particularly homogeneous bright white,
inhomogeneous with or without horizontal bands,
inhomogeneous gray,
inhomogeneous gray to black,
inhomogeneous black,